# Puppeteer block for element to appear without sleeping/waiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to loop through an array containing URLs and push an element into another array.

This is the code i used:

```
for (var i=0; i < links.length ; i++){
    await page.goto(links[i], { timeout: 0, waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded'] });
    await page.waitFor(20000); 

    var values = await page.evaluate(
        () => [...document.querySelectorAll('.XYZ')]
        .map(element => element.getAttribute('src'))
        ); //get the elements location
        media.push(values); // push to array
    );
    console.log(media);
}
```

This code works. However, notice the third line is an `await page.waitFor(20000);`.

I am using this, to wait so that the page has loaded.
If I omit this line, sometimes, the variable called `values` is `undefined`.

I experimented with other time delay values and the lower it gets, the more chance it has of being undefined.

What is the proper way to loop through the array without wasting unneccesary time with big delays?

Shouldn't this process be automatic since I am using `waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded']` in the `page.goto()` method?

Comment: You should call .waitFor for the page to load. That's why you have await keyword in-front of page evaluation. I use puppeteer and never had this issue. I suspect error is else where.

Comment: It's not evident that elements in use appear on domcontentloaded.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions of what is causing this behaviour or what should i do?

Comment: Considering you are using the `evaluate` method to retrieve all elements with class name `XYZ` from the UI, why not use `page.waitForSelector()` to ask puppeteer to wait for the last loaded element using that class to be loaded in the UI? By doing so you will know that all the elements you are interested in will have loaded before your `evaluate` method is triggered. That will be much more efficient than asking it to wait for a hardcoded amount of 20 seconds each time. You want to avoid using hardcoded sleep calls at all times.

Comment: @AJC24 ^Should be the answer

Comment: @ AJC24 omg it was so obvious. I feel so dumb because i have already used waitForSelector(). Please do an answer so i can upvote it and select it as the accepted answer so you get reputation (it seems people care a lot for rep on this site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you are using the evaluate method to retrieve all elements with class name XYZ from the UI, why not use `page.waitForSelector()` to ask puppeteer to wait for the last loaded element using that class to be loaded in the UI?

By doing so you will know that all the elements you are interested in will have loaded before your evaluate method is triggered.

That will be much more efficient than asking it to wait for a hardcoded amount of 20 seconds each time. You want to avoid using hardcoded wait calls at all times during automation.